# GUI ssh clients for mac?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

Is there a GUI ssh tunneling client for mac that supports jump servers? Mulitple hops?

I have tried:

- coachilla
- SSH tunnel manager
- Tunnelblick

tunneling manually through terminal is fine, but time consuming and I have hundreds of servers I have to log into and it is much easier if I can use a client. All the clients I have found work, but they can't handle jumping through jump host first and then server.

Does anyone know of any Mac GUI ssh tunelling clients that are capable of this?

THanks in advance.